# Comparar dois DataFrame e criar um novo DataFrame

Tags: python, comparação

Estou com uma dúvida e gostaria da ajuda de vocês. Tenho dois *DataFrame* e preciso comparar se algumas colunas destes *DataFrame* são iguais e, caso sejam iguais, então preciso armazenar os registros em um outro *DataFrame*. Ou seja, eu preciso criar um novo *DataFrame* a partir da comparação de outros dois.
O exemplo é referente ao ***df1*** e ***df2*** (preciso comparar 4 critérios - *'x', 'y', 'z', 'w'*) e após a comparação criar o ***dfNovo*** com os registros que foram verdadeiros na comparação. No caso do exemplo abaixo, o ***dfNovo*** seria formado pelo registro de **índice 0 do df1** e pelo registro de **índice 0 do df2**, já que são iguais nos critérios mencionados.

```
 import pandas as pd

 df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x": ['f','m','f'],
                        "y": [11,22,39], 
                        "z": ['C','nC','nC'], 
                        "w": ['F','S','M'],
                        "var1":["no", "yes", "no"],
                        "var2":["yes", "yes", "yes"],
                        "var3":["no", "no", "no"],
                        "classe":["yes", "yes", "no"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x": ['f','f','m'],
                        "y": [11,22,40], 
                        "z": ['C','C','nC'], 
                        "w": ['F','M','M'],
                        "var1":["yes", "yes", "no"],
                        "var2":["no", "no", "yes"],
                        "var3":["no", "no", "yes"],
                        "classe":["no", "yes", "yes"]})
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

muito boa a sua pergunta, pois a qualquer momento podemos precisar fazer esse procedimento nesse link acredito que já tenha a solução: [Compare two DataFrames and output their differences side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/compare-two-dataframes-and-output-their-differences-side-by-side)

E aqui na biblioteca pandas tem algo sobre comparar dataframes:
[pandas.DataFrame.equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html)

Answer (score 0):

Baseado no exemplo dado, a solução seria usar o método `merge`

```
>>> dfNovo = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'])

>>> dfNovo
   x   y  z  w var1_x var2_x var3_x classe_x var1_y var2_y var3_y classe_y
0  f  11  C  F     no    yes     no      yes    yes     no     no       no
```

Você pode definir o sufixo que desejar

```
>>> dfNovo = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'], suffixes=['_left', '_right'])

>>> dfNovo
   x   y  z  w var1_left var2_left var3_left classe_left var1_right var2_right var3_right classe_right
0  f  11  C  F        no       yes        no         yes        yes         no         no           no

>>> dfNovo = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'], suffixes=['_df1', '_df2'])

>>> dfNovo
   x   y  z  w var1_df1 var2_df1 var3_df1 classe_df1 var1_df2 var2_df2 var3_df2 classe_df2
0  f  11  C  F       no      yes       no        yes      yes       no       no         no
```

Espero ter ajudado